# How do I link specific buttons to a div which content can vary based on which button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm pretty new to JavaScript and HTML, and I was wondering how I can make a menu which allows you to make specific content in div(s) visible based on which button(picture1-12) was clicked. I think it should be possible to make one div which can output String linked to that specific button. I hope I'm clear enough. Is there anyone who could help me?

```css
body{
background-color: #A50000;
}
#Container{
width: 90%; 
margin: 0 auto;
}
.CenterImage{
text-align: center;
}
.Menu{
float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <title>Test_Site</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ID="Container">
         <div class="CenterImage">
            <img src="images\HeaderImage.jpg" alt="HeaderImage" width="100%">
         </div>
         <div class="Menu">
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture1.png" alt="Button_1" style="position: absolute; top: 210px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture2.png" alt="Button_2" style="position: absolute; top: 320px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture3.png" alt="Button_3" style="position: absolute; top: 430px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture4.png" alt="Button_4" style="position: absolute; top: 540px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture5.png" alt="Button_5" style="position: absolute; top: 650px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture6.png" alt="Button_6" style="position: absolute; top: 760px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture7.png" alt="Button_7" style="position: absolute; top: 870px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture8.png" alt="Button_8" style="position: absolute; top: 980px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture9.png" alt="Button_9" style="position: absolute; top: 1090px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture10.png" alt="Button_10" style="position: absolute; top: 1200px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture11.png" alt="Button_11" style="position: absolute; top: 1310px;"/>
            <img src="images/Buttons/Picture12.png" alt="Button_12" style="position: absolute; top: 1420px;"/>    
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to do. Do you want that when you click on an image on `div.Menu` the content of `div.CenterImage` should change? And if so to what exactly? Do you plan to use plain js or something like jQuery? If plain JS, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp.

Comment: no, I did not create the div yet, the content should appear in the green box http://prntscr.com/clw17s. I was thinking about JS, but I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: If you are not familiar with JS, I'd suggest you pick up a [JS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) or [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) tutorial. Without a basic understanding of how to select objects of the DOM, placing event listeners, etc. you won't be able to modify any code we present to you.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help though. I'm a C# and Java programmer, not JS and that kind of stuff :P

Comment: Well, JS's syntax is very similar to C, C++, C#, Java so that shouldn't be a problem. `jQuery` wraps a lot of functionality of JS in its functions so that you can do stuff like this `$("dev.menu img").click(function() { ... });`. But it is important to understand some basic stuff about JS, like anonymous functions which are used a lot in JS. If you already know how to code in Java/C# you should be able to go through these tutorials pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the ids and styles according to your situation. I think this is the one you looking for.

```
<div style='display:none' id='Button_1'>button1 content</div>
<div style='display:none' id='Button_12'>button12content</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function() {
   $('.Menu img').click(function() {
     if ($(this).attr("alt") == 'Button_1')
       $('#greenbox').html($('#Button_1'.html()));
   });
 });
</script>
```